# Springboot role authentication not working. I cannot access a specific path,

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, roles

I am new with springboot and I am finding some difficulties with the role based authentication.

I have built the following classes:

When a user logs in, I grant him the BACKOFFICE role:

```
package com.mb.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.mb.repo.IUserRepo;

@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private IUserRepo repo;


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        com.mb.model.User loggedUser = repo.findByEmail(username);

        List<GrantedAuthority> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("BACKOFFICE"));

        UserDetails userDet = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(loggedUser.getEmail(), loggedUser.getPassword(), roles);

        return userDet;
    }

}
```

And in the SecurityConfig file, I let that role access th /bo url.

```
package com.mb;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

import com.mb.service.UserService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private UserService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bcrypt;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder pe = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return pe;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bcrypt);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/bo/**").hasRole("BACKOFFICE")
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/", "/a").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

}
```

When I try to access with a not logged user I can access the / and /a, but not the /b URL. When I log in I can access the /b URL(every user has the BACKOFFICE role at the moment). But I cant access the /bo URL.

Sat Jul 27 12:02:08 CEST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Forbidden

Any suggestion?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: The most representative traces are these:

2019-07-27 14:35:04.760 DEBUG 15332 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied

Comment: Solved!! It seems as if when the role is granted to the user ¡, it must be specified as ROLE_ADMIN, but when you specify the secured paths, it must be done without the ROLE_. Just ADMIN. Springboot automatically adds "ROLE_" to the role itself. (ROLE_ to ADMIN --> ROLE_ADMIN). Thank you so much!!!